# My guest account is part of administrators group. How do I turn it into a normal guest account?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, administrator, guest-account

My guest account is part of administrators group.  How do I turn it into a normal guest account?  Accidentally, a user on this PC gave full privileges to guest account, and I'd like to undo that.

Comment: I hope you put a lead pipe to the user...

Comment: Check.  What else do i need to do :)

Comment: I also disabled the guest account for now.  It would be nice to have it enabled and working as it should.

Answer (score 1):

*Try this:*

1. Log in as Guest
2. Go to your control panel and select "***User Accounts***"
3. Click on the "***Change your account type***" action
4. Select "***Standard User***"

This works on Vista, and [this walkthru](http://www.techtalkz.com/windows-7/516139-managing-user-accounts-windows-7-a.html) seems to indicate that Windows 7 is similar.

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: @gchernis: In what way did it not work?